# How can I use modal in muidatatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I wanted to have a modal with a textfield and submitbutton, and also a cancel button to close the modal in the custom body render. How can I do this in mui-datatable? So far, I only applied a cancel button, I didn't know how to implement the modal or using the Dialog of material-ui.

```
class Orders extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      orders: [],
    };
  }


  columns = [
    "Cancel",
    {
      name: "Cancel",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {
          return (
             <FormControlLabel
          value={value}
          control={
            <Button value={value} variant="outlined" color="secondary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
          }
          onClick={(e) => {
            try {
              firestore.collection("orders").doc(tableMeta.rowData[0]).set(
                {
                  order: "Cancelled",
                },
                { merge: true }
              );
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          }}
        />
          );
        },
      },
    },
  ];
  options = {
    filter: true,
    responsive: "simple",
  };


  render() {
    return this.state.orders ? (
      <div>
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Orders"}
          columns={this.columns}
          data={this.state.orders}
          options={this.options}
        />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    );
  }
}
export default Orders;
```